# React Js : How to display a component only once in the dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm fresh new to React and trying to build a simple Blog project.

This blog will display a list of posts and visitors can click on the comments to show them below the post.

Here is my problem, i want a specific behavior witch is i want the user to be able to display only one comment box/window at a time.

If you click on another comments link, i want to force the others to close.

I don't figure out how to do this...

Here is some code to represent my actual App : [CondeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-comments-box-only-once-4qwkm?file=/src/App.js)

And sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another, you need to have shared state between all the comments in order to do this. That takes you at least back two layers, to `DisplayPosts`. You could pass the `state` and `setState` down, or you could use a context.

Here's [your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-comments-box-only-once-forked-dpfuv?file=/src/App.js) modified to use shared state through a context. Here's what that involves in a nutshell:

First in the App.js (or DisplayPosts, doesn't really matter), you create the Context and wrap the return with the Provider:

```
export const CommentContext = createContext(-1);
export default function App() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(-1);
  return (
    <CommentContext.Provider value={{ post, setPost }}>
      <div className="App">...</div>
    </CommentContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

next in the Posts.js, you just need to useContext instead of useState:

```
const Post = ({ props }) => {
  const { post, setPost } = useContext(CommentContext);
  const { id, title, comments } = props;
  const handleClick = (e) => { // ...
    setPost((pid) => (pid === id ? -1 : id));
  };

  return (<>...
      {post === id ? <DisplayComments postId={id} /> : null}
    </>);
};
```

That way you have one state for show comments, and it's the id of the post which should show comments. And if no comments should be shown, it gets set to -1 (I'm assuming you don't have a -1 id...you could use null or anything in that place though.

*Edit: in the sandbox I refactored the code a little for better separation of components. I put all the Context/Provider stuff in DisplayComments, with a very basic wrapper provider component imported into App. That way it keeps the comment logic and state out of the main App function.

I'm leaving the sample code here unchanged, because it keeps the code shorter and simpler, for illustration purposes.

Comment: Great thank you. I was thinking of using React Portals but your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to define a new state value on your `DisplayPosts` component.

DisplayPosts.js

```js
const DisplayPosts = () => {
  const [openedComments, setOpenedComments] = useState();

  const handleCommentOpen = (id) => {
    if (openedComments === id)
        setOpenedComments(null)
    else 
        setOpenedComments(id)
  }

  return data.map((post) => (
          <Post openedComments onCommentsOpen={() => handleCommentOpen(post.id)} key={post.id} props={post} />
        ))
}
```

Post.js

```js
const Post = ({ openedComments, onCommentsOpen }) => {
  return (
     <a href="/#" onClick={onCommentsOpen}>
        Comments: {comments}
     </a>
     {openedComments === id && <DisplayComments postId={id} />}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a state variable to track which box/window/id is being displayed at any one time.
When you render, only display each comment if the box/window matches the desired one.
Make the buttons on each comment change the 'displayed' state to the relevant one:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const comments = [
  "This is great.",
  "This is good.",
  "This is ok.",
  "This is bad."
];

export const MyScreen = props => {

   const [openComment, setOpenComment] = useState();

   return <div>
     { comments.map((comment, idx) => {
         return <div key={idx}>
           { openComment === idx ? comment : null }
           <button onClick={() => setOpenComment(idx)>View</button>
         </div>;
       }) }
   </div>;
};
```